# JPA entity gets updated on Ubuntu but throws Optimistic Locking Exception on Windows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Consider this example in which I have created two JPA entities and used Spring Data JPA repositories to perform simple CRUD -

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractValueObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "time_stamp")
    private Timestamp version;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (id == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return id.toString();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "demo")
public class Demo extends AbstractValueObject {
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "demo")
    private List<Owner> owners;

    public Demo() {
        owners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Owner> getOwners() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(owners);
    }

    public void addOwner(Owner owner) {
        this.owners.add(owner);
        owner.setDemo(this);
    }

    public void addAllOwners(List<Owner> owners) {
        this.owners.addAll(owners);

        for (Owner owner : owners) {
            owner.setDemo(this);
        }
    }

    public void update(Demo demo) {
        this.setName(demo.getName());
        this.owners.clear();
        this.addAllOwners(demo.getOwners());
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner")
public class Owner extends AbstractValueObject {
    private String attribute;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "demo_id", nullable = false)
    private Demo demo;

    public String getAttribute() {
        return attribute;
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public Demo getDemo() {
        return demo;
    }

    public void setDemo(Demo demo) {
        this.demo = demo;
    }
}
```

After that, I have created a JPA repository for the `Demo` entity, extending from `JpaRepository` -

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DemoRepository extends JpaRepository<Demo, Long> {}
```

Corresponding service implementation -

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {
    @Resource
    private DemoRepository demoRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Demo create(Demo demo) {
        return demoRepository.save(demo);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Demo update(long id, Demo demo) {
        Demo dbDemo = demoRepository.findOne(id);
        if (dbDemo == null) {
            return demo;
        }

        dbDemo.update(demo);
        return dbDemo;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void testRun() {
        Owner owner = new Owner();
        owner.setAttribute("attribute");

        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.setName("demo");
        demo.addOwner(owner);

        this.create(demo);

        demo.setName("another");
        this.update(demo.getId(), demo);
    }
}
```

persistence.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa-optimistic-locking" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Spring app-context.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking" />
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking.repository" />

    <bean id="demoService" class="com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking.service.DemoServiceImpl" />

    <!-- JPA/Database/Transaction Configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="admin123" />

        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="2" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="maxStatements" value="5" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="500" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="1000" />
        <property name="loginTimeout" value="800" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jpa-optimistic-locking" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="persistenceProvider">
            <bean class="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Now whenever I try to update an entity like this on Windows 7 -

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DemoService demoService = (DemoService) SpringHelper.INSTANCE.getBean("demoService");
        demoService.testRun();
    }
}
```

I get an exception like this -

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException:
>   Object of class
>   [com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking.domain.Demo] with
>   identifier [4]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by
>   another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect) :
>   [com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking.domain.Demo#4]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:519)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.testRun(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking.App.main(App.java:9)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or
>   deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was
>   incorrect) :
>   [com.keertimaan.example.jpaoptimisticlocking.domain.Demo#4]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.check(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2541)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3285)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
>     ... 9 more

If I run the same example in Ubuntu, then **I get no exception at all and my application completes successfully**. Why is that?

I am using Windowsw 7 64-bit edition -

> OS Name: Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
>
> OS Version: 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 Build 7601

and my Ubuntu version is 12.04.5 64-bit edition.

JDK used in Windows: jdk7 update 75

JDK used in Ubuntu: jdk7 update 51

MySQL Server version in Windows: 5.6.23-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

MySQL Server version in Ubuntu: 5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling that this is related to the timestamp precision of MySQL 5.6. MySQL 5.6.4 introduced microsecond precision, which will cause a version mismatch, and the locking will fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to your problem directly but in a **highly concurrent** environment you should not use `timestamp` as your `version` as two entity might have the same time! It's better to use a `long`/`int` version like below-

`@Version
long version;`

Also from design perspective please make your super class `abstract` as well. Can you check if changing these solves your problem?